# OpenAPI-generator how to know if the generated class is a request body object

Tags: openapi-generator

When model classes are generated in Java, I have in my template a check that if the property is a container (List/Map) then I perform a null check. For the sake of defensive programming, I would like to return an empty collection/map if this field is null.

**So the template looks like this:**

```
  {{/vars}}
  public {{classname}}({{#vars}}@JsonProperty("{{baseName}}") {{#required}}@lombok.NonNull {{/required}}{{>nullableDataType}} {{name}}{{#hasMore}},
        {{/hasMore}}{{/vars}}) {
    {{#vars}}
    {{#isContainer}}
        if ({{name}} == null) {
            this.{{name}} = {{#isListContainer}}Collections.emptyList();{{/isListContainer}}{{#isMapContainer}}Collections.emptyMap();{{/isMapContainer}}
        }
    {{/isContainer}}
    {{^isContainer}}
        this.{{name}} = {{name}};
    {{/isContainer}}
    {{/vars}}
}
{{#vars}}
```

**What will be translated into this:**

```
public MyRequestBodyObject(@JsonProperty("someField") String someField,
        @JsonProperty("dates") List<Period> dates) {
        this.someField = someField;
        if (dates == null) {
            this.dates = Collections.emptyList();
        }
}
```

This works well for deserialisation of responses but the problem is that request body objects are also having the same behaviour now.

For request body objects I think it makes sense to have a distinction between an empty or null list since it can have a different meaning.

I'm aware of the isBodyParam variable but this is only set to true when defined in the endpoint but not when it is a `$ref` object.

**Question**

Is there a way how I know whether the current object is a payload object or not?